# How to use if statement inside JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How to use if statement inside JSON Here is the code:
.......................................................................................

```
var config =
             [
                {
                    "name"      : "SiteTitle",
                    "bgcolor"   : "",
                    "color"     : "",
                    "position"  : "TL",
                    "text"      : "step1",
                    "time"      : 5000
                },
                {
                    "name"      : "Jawal",
                    "bgcolor"   : "",
                    "color"     : "",
                    "text"      : "step2",
                    "position"  : "BL",
                    "time"      : 5000
                },
                {
                    "name"      : "Password",
                    "bgcolor"   : "",
                    "color"     : "",
                    "text"      : "step3",
                    "position"  : "TL",
                    "time"      : 5000
                }
            ],

            //define if steps should change automatically
            autoplay    = false,
            //timeout for the step
            showtime,
            //current step of the tour
            step        = 0,
            //total number of steps
            total_steps = config.length;
```

This is the required result something like this:

```
    var config =
         [

    if(page==true)  {               
            {
                "name"      : "SiteTitle",
                "bgcolor"   : "",
                "color"     : "",
                "position"  : "TL",
                "text"      : "step1",
                "time"      : 5000
            },
            {
                "name"      : "Jawal",
                "bgcolor"   : "",
                "color"     : "",
                "text"      : "step2",
                "position"  : "BL",
                "time"      : 5000
            }
    } else {
            {
                "name"      : "Password",
                "bgcolor"   : "",
                "color"     : "",
                "text"      : "step3",
                "position"  : "TL",
                "time"      : 5000
            }
    }
        ],

            //define if steps should change automatically
            autoplay    = false,
            //timeout for the step
            showtime,
            //current step of the tour
            step        = 0,
            //total number of steps
            total_steps = config.length;
```

Actually this way is wrong and makes a JavaScript syntax error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's regular JavaScript, not JSON. Move the `if` statement outside:

```
if (page) {
    var config = [
        {
            "name"      : "SiteTitle",
            "bgcolor"   : "",
            "color"     : "",
            "position"  : "TL",
            "text"      : "step1",
            "time"      : 5000
        }, {
            "name"      : "Jawal",
            "bgcolor"   : "",
            "color"     : "",
            "text"      : "step2",
            "position"  : "BL",
            "time"      : 5000
        }
    ];
} else {
    var config = [
        {
            "name"      : "Password",
            "bgcolor"   : "",
            "color"     : "",
            "text"      : "step3",
            "position"  : "TL",
            "time"      : 5000
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: This will make a syntax error because you have complementary code

, autoplay    = false,
            showtime,
            step        = 0,
            total_steps = config.length;

Comment: @MontaserEl-sawy: No, not really. Try it.

Comment: Tried it the code will be:

if (settingsPage) {
    var config = [
    {
     "name"      : "SiteTitle",
     "bgcolor"   : "",
     "color"     : "",
     "position"  : "TL",
     "text"      : "step1",
     "time"      : 5000
    }
    
    ];
   } else {
    var config = [
    {
     "name"      : "Password",
     "bgcolor"   : "",
     "color"     : "",
     "text"      : "step3",
     "position"  : "TL",
     "time"      : 5000
    }
    ];
   }
    ,
    autoplay = false,
    showtime,
    step  = 0,
    total_steps = config.length;
try it and tell me what happen??

Comment: You have a comma after the last bracket of the `else` statement, but aside from that, it should work.

Comment: @MontaserEl-sawy: You should get rid of it and make your variable declarations local by prepending them with `var`.

Comment: Sorry i'm not profissional in javascript and jquery could you do that for me?

Comment: @MontaserEl-sawy: Nope, you figure it out.

Answer (score 19):

Validating the [JSON Schema Draft-07](https://json-schema.org/draft-07/json-schema-release-notes.html), JSON now supports the `if...then...else` keywords for conditional data representation.

Here is a quick example:

```
{
    "type": "integer",
    "minimum": 1,
    "maximum": 1000,
    "if": { "minimum": 100 },
    "then": { "multipleOf": 100 },
    "else": {
        "if": { "minimum": 10 },
        "then": { "multipleOf": 10 }
    }
}
```

### Edits

Using the OP's example in the context, it can be written like this:

```json
{
    "if": {
        "page": true
    },
    "then": [
        {
            "name": "SiteTitle",
            "bgcolor": "",
            "color": "",
            "position": "TL",
            "text": "step1",
            "time": 5000
        },
        {
            "name": "Jawal",
            "bgcolor": "",
            "color": "",
            "text": "step2",
            "position": "BL",
            "time": 5000
        }
    ],
    "else": [
        {
            "name": "Password",
            "bgcolor": "",
            "color": "",
            "text": "step3",
            "position": "TL",
            "time": 5000
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I think this one should be the right answer, according to recent updates.

Comment: Was hoping you could adapt your example to the question, rather than provide the example I've just seen in VSCode's Release Notes 1.27.2.

Comment: @Leo This is the standard illustration example as given by https://json-shema.org, which can be found here => https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/numeric.html#numeric. Although this was added as an example to the latest VS Code release, but that does not mean it was copied. Even though it was, this is an illustration of how it works, so I don't think it is bad

Comment: @Erisan not bad, but not an answer. Consider not ignoring OP's example.

Comment: @Leo Oh well, it's an answer, but not illustrating the OP's examples. Thanks though.

Comment: Thanks, I have made an edit to use the OP's examples.

Comment: @ErisanOlasheni How to evaluate such type of JSON in python or any other programming language, if JSON has logical data?

Answer (score 2):

you can add an if inside JSON.

```
const config = [
...(page ? [
     {
        "name"      : "SiteTitle",
        "bgcolor"   : "",
        "color"     : "",
        "position"  : "TL",
        "text"      : "step1",
        "time"      : 5000
    },
    {
        "name"      : "Jawal",
        "bgcolor"   : "",
        "color"     : "",
        "text"      : "step2",
        "position"  : "BL",
        "time"      : 5000
    }] : [{
        "name"      : "Password",
        "bgcolor"   : "",
        "color"     : "",
        "text"      : "step3",
        "position"  : "TL",
        "time"      : 5000
    }]),
];
```

Answer (score 0):

or perhaps this:

```
 var config =
  (page == true) ?
     [             
        {
            "name"      : "SiteTitle",
            "bgcolor"   : "",
            "color"     : "",
            "position"  : "TL",
            "text"      : "step1",
            "time"      : 5000
        },
        {
            "name"      : "Jawal",
            "bgcolor"   : "",
            "color"     : "",
            "text"      : "step2",
            "position"  : "BL",
            "time"      : 5000
        }
  :
        {
            "name"      : "Password",
            "bgcolor"   : "",
            "color"     : "",
            "text"      : "step3",
            "position"  : "TL",
            "time"      : 5000
        }
    ];
```

Comment: No it is not working because after if statment i have to put some  complementary code like this: 

, autoplay = false, showtime, step = 0, total_steps = config.length;

Comment: you could have just added a comma at the end of the last bracket for my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way also (not saying this is the best way but it's another way and could be useful in some scenarios)

```
let config = [];
if (page) {
   config.push({
        "name"      : "SiteTitle",
        "bgcolor"   : "",
        "color"     : "",
        "position"  : "TL",
        "text"      : "step1",
        "time"      : 5000
    });
   config.push({
        "name"      : "Jawal",
        "bgcolor"   : "",
        "color"     : "",
        "text"      : "step2",
        "position"  : "BL",
        "time"      : 5000
    });
} else {
    config.push({
        "name"      : "Password",
        "bgcolor"   : "",
        "color"     : "",
        "text"      : "step3",
        "position"  : "TL",
        "time"      : 5000
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library [jsoncode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsoncode) that allows you to apply logical expressions directly into JSON and get the necessary result according to the transmitted model:

```js
import jsoncode from './jsoncode.lib.mjs';

const json_src = {
    "configs [AS ARRAY]": {
        "[...IF page]": [
            {
                "name": "SiteTitle",
                "bgcolor": "",
                "color": "",
                "position": "TL",
                "text": "step1",
                "time": 5000
            }, {
                "name": "Jawal",
                "bgcolor": "",
                "color": "",
                "text": "step2",
                "position": "BL",
                "time": 5000
            }
        ],
        "[IF !page]": {
            "name": "Password",
            "bgcolor": "",
            "color": "",
            "text": "step3",
            "position": "TL",
            "time": 5000
        }
    }
};

const configsA = jsoncode(json_src, { page: true  }).configs;
const configsB = jsoncode(json_src, { page: false }).configs;

console.log('configsA:', configsA);
console.log('configsB:', configsB);
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsoncode